# Multiply a SUM by another column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to multiply a `SUM` statement with another column.  For instance:

```
SELECT SUM(Orders.Sales)
```

To get the total sales.

```
SELECT Employee.Commission_Percentage
```

To get the commission percentage.

If I want to combine these into

```
SELECT SUM(Orders.Sales) * Employee.Commission_Percentage AS 'Total Income'
```

I have to put `Employee.Commision_Percentage` in the `GROUP BY` clause.  This throws the calculation off.  Is there any other way to multiply a `SUM` by another column result without putting it in an aggregate or `GROUP BY`?

Comment: The `FROM` and the join condition are relevant

Answer (score 2):

If you want the total commissions:

```
SELECT SUM(o.Sales * e.Commission_Percentage) 
FROM Orders o JOIN
     Employee e
     ON o.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId;
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but now I have another in the same query.  I have a query that calculates the commission by multiplying commission percentage by sales, using the format above.  I need to add that SUM to the employee's base salary via:  SELECT SUM(o.Sales * e.Commission_Percentage) + e.Salary.   Again, I am having to either add e.Salary to an aggregate or GROUP BY clause, and when I do the calculation is way off.  I know the salary and the commission total, but it is not adding them correctly.  I suspect it has to do with the group by clause.

Comment: @user3788316 . . . If you have another question, then you should ask another question.  You should also include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery...  Something similar to this:

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  s.sales * e.commission_percentage as total_income
from
  employee e
  join (
    select
      o.employee_id, sum (o.sales) as sales
    from orders.sales as o
    group by o.employee_id ) s on
  e.employee_id = s.employee_id
```